# Pinch and group in WinRT

Tags: .net, xaml, user-interface, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is there a built in control that allows you to swap child elements when zooming out?

Similar to how when you go to "All Apps" on the start screen, you can pinch on the tiles and have them grouped and sorted into alphabets A-Z.

Is this a custom functionality that will require manually handling the gesture or is there an easier approach to detect the pinch/zoom?

Comment: Check out this awesome [blog post](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/gridview-with-inline-group-headers), it's what you want

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the SemanticZoom control.

```xaml
<SemanticZoom ...>
   <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
     <a control that implements ISemanticZoomInfo />
   </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
   <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
     <a control that implements ISemanticZoomInfo />
   </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
</SemanticZoom>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.semanticzoom